# W: Problem unlinking the file lists - Clean (21: Is a directory) Error when running 'sudo apt-get update'

Tags: apt

I started seeing this error msg
    `W: Problem unlinking the file lists - Clean (21: Is a directory)`

whenever I tried to update using apt.

I have already tried `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get  autoclean`

but still the problem persists.

Need help pls. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1 64-bit

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/765274/error-problem-unlinking-in-apt-get-clean

Comment: I don't use `apt-fast` and do not have this installed so that solution is not relevant

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delete all files in `/var/lib/apt/lists/` and re-run `apt-get update`.

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Comment: works as well. Thanks!